# Send error message when the user don't have perm (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, permissions, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot, and wanna add a ""you dont have permission to use this command" message when te user don't have perm to use a command
I tryed for a few hours (with if's and else's) and can't find a way

```
    @commands.command(aliases=['limpar'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount : int):
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
            embed=discord.Embed(title="", url="", description=f"Squeaky clean!!!", color=0x000000)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=2)
            print('Squeaky clean!!!')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a error handler event, it will be for all the commands.

```py
@commands.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You do not have {commands.MissingPermissions.missing_perms} to run this command.")
```

[`commands.MissingPermissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions)